# How to enter two inputs in Body of postman

Tags: python, api, postman

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def Addition(x):
    number1=json.loads(x.body)
    addition=str(number1+6)

    return JsonResponse(" Addition is :"+addition+".",safe=False)
```

This is working code.
Can any one please tell me how to add two inputs in body of postman for addition.

Answer (score 0):

First, A GET request shouldn't have a body [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

I don't think postman gives an option to pass body to a GET request. But you can pass parameter to a GET request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET